# Разворот картинки java

Tags: java

Что то не получается развернуть картинку.

Написал два метода, что-то неучел.

Первый метод должен разворачивать картинку:

```
@Override
public void rotateSprite(float rotation_angle, int x, int y){
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Rect dstRect = new Rect();
    dstRect.left = x;
    dstRect.top = y;
    dstRect.right = x + bitmap.getWidth();
    dstRect.bottom = y + bitmap.getHeight();
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(rotation_angle,  bitmap.getWidth() + (bitmap.getWidth() / 2), dstRect.top +(bitmap.getHeight() / 2));
    //canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, dstRect, dstRect, null);
    //canvas.restore();
}
```

А второй потом прорисовывать:

```
@Override
public void drawImage(Image Image, int x, int y) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidImage)Image).bitmap, x, y, null);
}
```

Что-то не получается ее вращать

Comment: Я, конечно, извиняюсь, НО: Вы точно к той переменной обращаетесь во втором фрагменте кода? Я к тому, что в методе создаётся локальная переменная: `Canvas canvas = new Canvas();`, а Вы во втором фрагменте кода обращаетесь к ней, как к глобальной...

Comment: алгоритм поворота только для квадратных изображений приведен